# Connecting to Google cloud SQL through my local machine

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I want to connect to my Google cloud SQL instance through MySQL workbench installed on my local machine. Using `ipconfig`, I determined the IPV4 address of my machine, but when I am trying to enter that IP address in

Edit > Access control > Authorization,

I get a message that `Private networks cannot be whitelisted.`

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add your public IP, not your (link) local one. You can find out your public IP for example on http://whatismyip.com/.